# Where is the main clause in "Like when I put a dead goldfish into Dr. Green's fish tank"?

Tags: clauses, parsing

> I admit it. I did a lot of things when I was younger that maybe I shouldn't have. ***Like when I put a dead goldfish into Dr. Green's fish tank.***

My question is

1. Is "like" a conjunction word in the sentence in bold?
2. Should the sentence in bold have the main clause? If it should, where is it?

Comment: The passage you quote is rather informal and conversational. A more formal version would be "I admit that when I was younger I did a lot of things that maybe I should not have done. For example, I put a dead goldfish into Dr. Green's fish tank," or "One of those things was...".

Comment: Apart from being "informal, conversational, I think the cited usage is also slightly suspect on purely syntactic grounds. If we replace "colloquial, slangy" ***like*** with ***for example*** or ***such as***, it seems to me the "correct" phrasing should also replace ***when I put a dead fish in his tank*** with an actual NOUN PHRASE that can properly serve as an example of the aforementioned ***lot of things***. Hence *I did a lot of things... **such as putting** a dead fish in his tank.* Where I see ***putting*** as a gerund / noun usage.

Comment: Note that strictly speaking there should probably be just a comma after the entirely optional clause ***that maybe I shouldn't have***. In which case it should be easy to see that  the "main clause" is ***I did a lot of things***. Everything else is just optional embellishment.

Comment: The second sentence is not a sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Like" in this context is used to mean "For instance".

The thinking behind it is:

"There were a number of incidents, and all of them had the same theme, and they all (in that way) *resembled* this following incident, in which I put a dead goldfish into Dr. Green's tank."

Answer (score 0):

In informal language there are structures that aren't full sentences:

> Lot of animals come into my garden. For example, birds.

The second part has be punctuated as a sentence and in some ways it expresses a new idea, but it does so without forming a sentence.  In formal writing you might write:

> ... For example, there are birds / ... For example, birds come into my garden. / For example, birds do.

There is no main clause in  "For example, birds." because there is no clause at all.

You example is more complex.  There is a subordinating conjuction "when" but no matrix clause. There is no main clause, and this is a sentence fragment. These are avoided in formal writing, but are quite common when speaking informally.

We would understand it this subordinate clause to function as either a complement

> Like, There was when I ...

or a subject

> Like, when I put ... tank was something I certainly should *not* have done.